# Python: How to clear text entry when that entry is clicked?

Tags: python, tkinter-entry

How can I clear a tkinter `entry` when being clicked?
I tried putting command like button but its not working.

```
self.entry1= Entry(self.mw,width=25,text=str1,justify=RIGHT,fg="red")
self.entry1.insert(INSERT, "type here..")
self.entry1.pack()
```

Answer (score 2):

All you need to do is bind the entry to a function that uses the `delete` function.

```
def clear(event):
    self.entry1.delete(0, END)

self.entry1= Entry(self.mw,width=25,text=str1,justify=RIGHT,fg="red")
self.entry1.insert(INSERT, "type here..")
self.entry1.bind('<Button-1>', clear())
self.entry1.pack()
```

Comment: thats the way to delete the text in entry right, but i want my text to be cleared upon clicking the entry field. How can i do that?